# What is "RFIS" tag

Tags: radio, rfid

I read somewhere about "RFIS" tag. I know what is "RFID" but does something called "RFIS" exist? I tried to search but all suggestions are RFID related. Would be nice if you have any clue share it please.

It could be just a mistake, so just simply it should have been RFID! or maybe this is something very new and no one knows about it!

This is a part of title:

**"a body area network composed of compass and tilt sensors and RFIS tags"**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost certainly a typo. Note that the <kbd>s</kbd> key is right next to the <kbd>d</kbd>.

But it may also refer to the new "Radio Frequency ISentification" technology, of course :-).

**edit** after your question update
The abstract talks about "intelligent guide to help blind people to solve puzzles". It's easily imaginable that RFID could be used to identify the puzzle pieces.

Comment: Now that you pointed out D and S keys are next to eachother it makes much more sense! Beleive it, this is part of title of on an project fo a PHD position so I was like this should be some serious new technology or something!

Comment: I had no idea we had the <kdb> tag. Cool stuff.

Comment: @drxzcl - I didn't know it either, but somebody else used it in a recent question or answer. We learn every day! :-)

Comment: aaa so you found it :D

Comment: @Sean87 - Ah, it wasn't even a challenge ;-)

Comment: @stevenvh Double Quoutes For The Win!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Acronyms Dictionary](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RFIS), it can be as well:

```
RFIS    Remote Frequency Indicator Selector
RFIS    RWS/Fire-Control Interface Software
RFIS    Radio Frequency Interface Subsystem/System
```

I have a hard time believing that someone could make a typo in PhD project title.

Comment: Sean hadn't told about the PhD yet when I posted, and it looks indeed hard to believe to have this kind of error in a project title, but there's still the reference to the "tag", so it doesn't look impossible to me.

Comment: @stevenvh, true :)

Comment: @stevenvh Sorry I was excited while posting my question, I gave more info in my question update maybe it can give more clue what they are talking about?

Comment: @Sean87 - There's also [acronymfinder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/RFIS.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is every indication that it is a "typo" as others have suggested.

The original text is as below, in relation to a 'pervasive systems' research incentive at a European university. Anyone else may find it in the same way that I did :-) :

- Have you ever tried to solve a puzzle blind folded? As strange as it may sound, it can be done if somebody next to you can act as your eyes; sees what you need to see and think for you. This is exactly what this project aims at doing but instead of having a person next to you, a body area network composed of compass and tilt sensors and RFIS tags will help you.

  The idea is through grouping, object identification, and recognizing interaction between hand and puzzle pieces to build an intelligent guide to help blind people to solve puzzles. Each puzzle piece needs to be identified, its association with other pieces needs to be recognized and guidance and feed back (in forms of voice or hepatic feedback ) should be given to the player while choosing puzzle pieces and trying to put the pieces in the right place with right orientation.

The term has no special meaning in "pervasive systems" .

The term is used in [this document](http://sce.umkc.edu/~leeyu/Artisan/NSF-Annual-Report.pdf) in answer to Q2.10

- 1. Pervasive computing using RFIS, multi-touch.

but it seems more likely to be a typo here than a new acronym.

---

It is common for people to make keyboard errors with no awareness of having done so. 
In another lifetime I worked for NZ Telecom. A newspaper article complained about the poor quality of city telephone service. Amongst other things they complained about excessive "wrong numbers". They provided an example list of target companies whose numbers had (allegedly) been dialled, and the companies which had been reached instead. Out of a list of about 10 companies I was able to show that in all except one or two cases there was a logical connection between the intended number and the actual number of the company dialled. Sometimes a transposition (eg <kbd>32</kbd> instead of <kbd>23</kbd>), sometimes an adjacent digit dialled (as in teh [<- whoops :-) ] case here of <kbd>RFID</kbd> and <kbd>RFIS</kbd> and sometimes an added or omitted leading digit.

Comment: hmmm it is no more top secret :D

Comment: @Sean87 - GoogleMeister :-)